# How to animate CSS resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #list { overflow:auto; }
    #list li { float:left; margin-right:10px; }

    div { width:500px; height:500px; border:1px solid gray; position:relative; }
    iframe { border:0 none; width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
    span.togglebutton { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background-color:black; padding:3px; color:white; }

    div.maximized { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:0 none; z-index:9; }
  </style>
```

This is being called:

```
$("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest("li").children("div").toggleClass("maximized");
});
```

Essentially it maximizes/minimizes my iFrame to be fullscreen. I want to animate the maximize and minimize. How can I go about doing this?

**UPDATE**
Here is my code using adeno's code:

```
$("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var currentText = $this.text();
        var theFrame = $(this).closest("li").children("div");

        if (currentText === "Maximize") {
            $this.text("Minimize");
            theFrame.animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"});
        }
        else {
            $this.text("Maximize");
            theFrame.animate({height: "50%", width: "50%"});
        }
    });
```

This works well, except I would like the maximize to take over the FULL screen. How can I do this?

Comment: I know [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) can do this.  While it might be overkill for a single animation, it's worth looking into if you're already using jQuery and are going to be doing more JS UI work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky to be quite honest... to make it behave correctly there is quite a lot that needs to be done.

[Here is a working demo using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/BT4hU/)

I hope you like it. I made it from scratch to ensure it would work. I added a (tool)bar on the top so it could hold my controls, with some tweaking you could make that an image and make the controls be right aligned to the container div.

Theres really no 'smarter' way to do this I think. The resize event bind / unbind is critical, without it this would break on a resize.

PS.; It's google that is making it a little wonky in the animation (it has resize events of it's own which are triggered constantly in the animation), I just couldn't think of a better website to use that also works in an iframe (stackoverflow doesn't).

**Edit:**

As per request in comments; here is a version for multiple frames on a page. Not thoroughly tested and could use some optimization but I am very tired so that is not going to happen today ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/BT4hU/35/

Comment: This is excellent. Could I see how this performs with a 2nd iframe ontop of the google.com iframe that also has a max/min button? Would it work for the top iframe animating full screen all the way to the bottom? That is essentially what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well you didn't mention multiple frames... But let me make some adjustments and that should be no problem

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to animate class transitions, but I think I would opt for something else.

Depends what minimized means, but you could look at toggle() instead of toggleClass() and drop the classes entirely as toogle allows animation, but hides the element completely.

Another option would be to just use animate() on height and width to maximize and minimize your iframe. With an if statement you could create a toggle effect on the sizes you wish to animate to and from.

There are some cross domain issues with iframes, but if it's working with toggleClass() it should probably work with animate() as well. Example assumes the iframe has an id of #myiframe, and it's not tested so there could be errors, just to show an example.

```
#myiframe { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:40%; height:40%; border:0 none; z-index:9; }
```

-

```
$("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
    var elm = $(this).closest("li").children("div");
    if (elm.css("height") == "40%") {
       elm.animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"});
    }
    else {
       elm.animate({height: "40%", width: "40%"});
    }
});
```

Edit: Another option would be to set the iframe size in pixels and animate it to the size of the screen:

```
#myiframe { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:400px; height:400px; border:0 none; z-index:9; }
```

-

```
$("span.togglebutton").click(function() {
    var H = window.height();
    var W = window.width();
    var elm = $(this).closest("li").children("div");
    if (elm.css("height") == "400px") {
       elm.animate({height: H, width: W});
    }
    else {
       elm.animate({height: "400px", width: "400px"});
    }
});
```

Maybe you could use that for someting, as not I'm not sure why the iframe does not animate to 100%, but it is probably constrained within an other element or someting like that, so it goes to 100%, only it does so within the element it is positioned in. Using absolute pixels gotten from the screen size should work, or maybe something inbetween? but unfortunately you can't mix pixels and percent in css/jQuery.
Using pixels would also require a function for updating the size on browser resize.

Comment: Can you show an example of using animate() on height and width to max/min the iframe?

Comment: This is great. I have updated my question, with your code. I would like the iframe to take over the whole screen when maximized. How can I achieve that? Right now the animation maximizes to the iframe full height/width, not the entire browser window

Comment: If the answer is correct, please accept it. Going fullscreen is considered bad practice, and doing so without opening a new window with window.open requires some hacks. Try searching on this site for fullscreen solutions, or ask a new question as this regards some completely different, i.e. forcing the browser to go full screen.

Comment: There is for instance in webkit the webkitRequestFullScreen(); function, not sure if something similar exists in all browser, but me thinks not, there's bound to be some browsers that does not support this, probably IE, and most likely Firefox as they frown upon such things.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-worded it. I don;t want to go full screen, I just want to take the iframe and maximize it within the page it is in.

Comment: And by the way, are you talking about the FULL screen or the FULL browser window, as they are not the same thing. Maybe I misunderstood ??? Edit: I see now, I misunderstood :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what your after:

[Class Transitions](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions)

Not sure how well it'll transition with fixed positioning, there's sure to be a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

chain the animation to your toggleClass, http://api.jquery.com/animate/